# One to one and onto

Tags: functions

I just wonder if these relations are one to one and onto:

1. the function $f = \{(1,a),(1,b),(1,c)\}$ from $X = \{1\}$ to $Y = \{a,b,c\}$.        I think this function is one to one and onto
2. the function $f = \{(1,a),(2,b),(4,d)\}$ from $X=\{1,2,3,4\}$ to $Y =\{a,b,c,d\}$. I think this function is one to one, but not onto

What do you think?

Comment: Neither of those are functions by the regular definition. The first one defines several mappings for one value, and the second doesn't define a mapping for 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I suggest you review the following link: [**definition of a function**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_%28mathematics%29#Definition), (mathematical).

- The entire entry is worth reviewing, as it includes additional information about functions and function notation, provides examples of functions, and defines "injective" (one-to-one), "surjective" (onto), and "bijective" (one-to-one and onto) functions.

Now:

(1) For the first example in your post, the relation is not by definition, a function, because it assigns *three different* values of $Y$ to *one value* in the domain, $X$, (or put differently, it maps $1 \in X$ to three distinct values in $Y$, which makes $f(1)$ not well-defined).

We can reverse the direction of the mapping to define $f_1: Y \to X,$ $f_1 = \{(a, 1), (b, 1)(c, 1)\}$, THEN $f_1$ is an ONTO function from $Y$ *onto* $X$, but is not be one-to-one, since the *image* under $f_1$ of each of the three *distinct* values in $Y$ identical: $f_1(a) = f_1(b) = f_1(c) = 1$.

---

(2) For the second example in your post:
There's no way to fix, in a similar manner, the second non-function; as it stands, it fails to be a function because the element $3 \in X$ has no image; that is, $f$ is not defined for $3 \in X$.

However, let's MAKE a function by defining $f_2$ so that $\exists f_(3):\quad$, e.g.$\quad f_2: X \to Y,\;$ $f_2 = \{(1, a), (2, b), (3, c), (4, d)\}$

Under this definition, $f_2$ is one-to-one and onto.

Recall, a function is generally defined as a relation which assigns a value from the range to EACH element in the domain on which it is defined, and it must map each element in the domain to *one, and only one,* element in the codomain/range.

Comment: Nicely done Amy. Have you ever seen a good reference in which someone showed that "How many one-one functions are there between two finite sets"?